# Command "Parameter Info" is not working in Android Studio 3.5

Tags: android, android-studio, android-shortcut

Before Android studio 3.5 **ctrl + p** is the command to find out possible parameters of a method but now it is not working as it was before, now it is showing me printing options on **ctrl + P**

Comment: Its working for me.. Which OS do you use?

Comment: windows 10, i have checked there is no shortcut key assign to parameter info, and ctrl + p is assign to print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

In the latest version Android Studio 3.5, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> is assigned to print(by default).

To assign a new key to `Parameter Info`, double click on the `Parameter Info -> Add Keyboard Shortcut` and press the key combination you wish to assign.

**ORIGINAL**

On Mac, it is still <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>  as older.
To find out what is the new key in windows pc.

Go to `File -> Settings -> Keymap -> Search for parameter info`

[image]

Comment: thanks dear in windows they have assign that key to print group and for parameter info they haven't set any shortcut

Comment: @ZubairAkber you can always set up a new key according to your needs.

Comment: @ZubairAkber i've modified my answer a bit.